# Socket.io server doesn't seem to get a connection?

Tags: node.js, chat, websocket, socket.io

I'm working my way through the tutorials on [NodeTuts](http://nodetuts.com/). I'm trying to get a chat server working using [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

I can start the node instance fine and I get the "socket.io ready - accepting connections" message when I do. When I point my browser at localhost:8888 I get served the html form from template.html also so that all looks good. I never seem to make a socket connection though and I never see the "Connection Received" log or the 'Welcome to the chat server' message.

Any ideas what the problem is?

```
var fs, http, io, server, socket, sys;
  http = require('http');
  fs = require('fs');
  sys = require('sys');
  io = require('socket.io');
  server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var rs;
    console.log('server started');
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    rs = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/template.html');
    return sys.pump(rs, res);
  });
  socket = io.listen(server);
  socket.on('connection', function(client) {
    var username;
    console.log('Connection received');
    client.send('Welcome to the chat server');
    client.send('Please enter a username');
    return client.on('message', function(message) {
      if (!username) {
        username = message;
        return client.send("Hi " + username + "!");
      } else {
        return socket.broadcast("" + username + ": " + message);
      }
    });
  });
  server.listen(8888);
```

Here's the JS part of template.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
      socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {port: 8888});
      socket.on('message', function(message) {
        var data = message.data
        data = data.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        console.log( data );
        $('#log ul').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
        window.scrollBy(0, 1000000000000000);
        entry_el.focus();
      });


      var entry_el = $('#entry');
      entry_el.keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode != 13) return;
        var msg = entry_el.attr('value');
        // if the message is not empty
        if (msg) {
            socket.send(msg);
            entry_el.attr('value', '');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What's in template.html? It looks like the error is probably in there...

Comment: The error is in the client side JavaScript.

Comment: Edited to add the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to call `socket.connect();` in your client-side code, right after `socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {port: 8888});`